# Link to Views page with token?

Tags: 7, views, tokens

I've got a Views (machine readable name: e.g 'views-events-page') page that I gave a URL (in the path field, e.g. 'events').

I want to link to this Views page from Link field. Of course, I can paste the path 'events' into the link field. But supposing I would change the path of the Views page the link will be broken. Is there any chance of using a token to get the path of this Views page, like `[views:view-events-page:path]`.

I was not lucky asking the search engine of choice the right question. I did not find any useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can [create a custom token](https://www.drupal.org/node/1143842) , [another helper link](https://benmarshall.me/drupal-custom-tokens/)

or use 
[Custom Token module](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_custom) 
then get views url  with

```
$view = views_get_view('viewname');
$view->set_display('display_name');
view->get_url(); // if not work try this  $view->get_path()
```

Learn how to create custom token according to below example

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_token_info().
 */
function my_module_token_info() {

  // Add tokens.
  $site['city_name'] = array(
    'name' => t('Token Name'),
    'description' => t('Token Description'),
  );

  return array(
    'tokens' => array(
      'site' => $site,
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_tokens().
 */
function my_module_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data = array(), array $options = array()) {
  $replacements = array();

 if ($type == 'site') {
    foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
      switch ($name) {
        case 'city_name':
          $city_name = variable_get('city_name');
          $replacements[$original] = $sanitize ? check_plain($city_name) : $city_name;
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  // Return the replacements.
  return $replacements;
}
```